# File Operations copying files

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation

When copying files I don't see any copying progress.

What file manager shows copying progress like Windows Explorer?

Comment: Please [edit] your post and mention what version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: There is a circle in the header bar on the right that gets progressively filled in Files. If you click on it you get more details.

Comment: Results of `lsb_release -a` please, and `ls /usr/bin/*session` in the case my answer below doesnt work for you

Comment: If you are on the KDE desktop and use Dolphin, you get a progress bar in the notification area for long operations.

Answer (score 1):

**Nautilus**, the default file manager in Ubuntu (Main flavor, Gnome-shell DE), has that feature. Most of the copying is instant, en there will be no "progress bar".

However, if you copy to a pendrive, you'll see the progression in the top right of nautilus.

---

*PS : it's Q&A, but make a little bit of effort in the question ! :-)*